# Custom bot command not working for discord bot made by discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So basically I've created a discord bot. It has the function to add role to users if the user writes a particular type of message on a particular channel. I've removed the default help command by this code `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=None)` but When the add role process is working the bot is ignoring the commands specially the help command the code is here:

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embeding = discord.Embed(description='Some Message')
    await ctx.send(embed=embeding)
```

How can I fix this issue?

I'm using `on_message` function for assigning roles

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. It is much better to _show us_ your code as a [mre] instead of describing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us your role command so there is only so much I can recommend.

First of all, you may be better of using the following code after you define your bot:

`bot.remove_command('help')`

Using an `on_message` function will often also disable your other commands, so be sure to add this line of code to the bottom of your `on_message` function:

`await bot.process_commands(message)`

Comment: I've added `await bot.process_commands(message)` btw I'm sharing the a sample role command I'm using in the code in one of the answer of the code. Can have help me to correct the code?

Comment: @SoumyajoyDas Yes, please edit your code into your question and I will help you debug it.

Comment: I've added an Answer Can you please check it? Indenting takes a lot of time in stackoverflow from mobile phone. It will be tough for me to indent it again

Comment: Does the code you answered with work in your bot? Do the other commands work?

Comment: The bot has only the help command I've not given any other command to the bot

Comment: Can you test the help command, though, and see if it responds?

Comment: Okay I'm testing But Ig it will not work

Comment: I tested the help command right now after activating the bot but it was not working as usual of the help command

Comment: Mully Baguire — Today at 9:02 AM
!19 help
[9:04 AM]
100-UG-CSE-2024

pikaBot
BOT
 — Today at 9:04 AM
Congratulations! You're now Verified! @v19 role is added!

Comment: Try my first recommendation:

Remove the `help_command=None` from when you define your bot and add a line of code under it that says `bot.remove_command("help")`

Comment: Where to add ```bot.remove_command("help")``` in my code can you tell me the nearby code and the indentation after which I will use this one?

Comment: Add it right under your `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")` line with no indentation.

Comment: Ok I'm trying I will let you know if it works

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: You aren't receiving any errors?

Comment: No I got no errors but the bot was not responding to the command

Comment: Your bot does respond to the role command, however, yes? If anything, I'd recommend just making the on_message function a command.

Comment: Can you try adding another command such as ping, just to make sure the problem is throughout all the commands and not just help?

Comment: Ok I'm checking

Comment: No ping command is not working as well I was supposed to reply Pong but it didn't

Comment: I just fixed the issue :D I shifted the code of on_message to @bot.listener(on_message) and it worked magically well. Now the bot is responding to commands as well as messages of same type :D. Thanks a lot for investing your time I can to know about a few things from you too. :D

Comment: @SoumyajoyDas the problem is in your role function, because when I erased it and added a simple on_message function in my own repl, the bot worked perfectly.

Comment: Alright that's awesome! Glad you figured it out